# Spring batch exception remove file content

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using a Spring batch job to load a file into database. The file contains sensitive customer data. On any parsing error, Spring batch logs the exception along with the file line content.

> Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[file [/path/file.txt]], input=[sensitive data]

I would like to avoid the possibility of those with access to copy paste the log in their communications with parties not authorized for this particular piece of data. Hence I disabled the Spring batch log using `application.properties` setting

```
logging.level.org.springframework.batch: OFF
```

However I still need to log the file name, line number and the cause of error. Thought of something like below in `StepExecutionListener::afterStep`, but this may not be foolproof/future-proof.

```
stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()
    .forEach(e -> log.error(e.getMessage().replaceAll("[, ]*input=\\[.*?]", "") + " - " + e.getCause()));
```

What other approaches can I try? Is there a setting to instruct Spring batch to mask/exclude the file content in the exception message?

Comment: Very interesting use case! Let me check what could be done to customize the way to log such exceptions.

Comment: I added an answer with an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not disable logs at a global level because this might be needed elsewhere in the app.

The extension point your are looking for is the [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/exception/ExceptionHandler.html) API. This is where you can customize exception handling during any phase of the chunk processing. In your case, you can catch flat file parsing exceptions and do whatever you need with them (log sensitive data to a secure source, customize the log by removing sensitive data, etc).

Here is a quick example:

```
class MyCustomExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleException(RepeatContext repeatContext, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
            FlatFileParseException exception = (FlatFileParseException) throwable;
            // customize the exception handling as needed
            System.err.println("Error while parsing line " + exception.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

Once that in place, you can register your exception handler in your step with `org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.AbstractTaskletStepBuilder#exceptionHandler`, something like:

```
@Bean
public Step myStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(2)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .exceptionHandler(new MyCustomExceptionHandler())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the ExceptionHandler to erase the sensitive data. Faced another case though, where the data line is part of the `exception.getCause()` instead of `exception.getMessage()`. I use a CompositeLineMapper, and tested with a non-matching pattern, which resulted in `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a matching pattern for key=[sensitive data]`. I am handling them case by case. Wish Spring Batch had a configuration to modify this data logging as needed.